# TCPClient no constructor that takes two arguments

Tags: c#

So I wanted to play around with some server client components in C# but ran into a problem when using the TCPClient. When instantiating it, I can't seem to access the constructor that takes a string and a int as per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/115ytk56(v=vs.110).aspx). Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Client
{
    internal class Client
    {

        private readonly int PORT = 2500;
        private readonly string IP = "127.0.0.1";

        public Client()
        {

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IP, PORT);
```

Comment: What framework version?  Are you using Core?  UWP?

Comment: That code compiles for me. Which version of .NET are you targeting? As an aside, I'd *strongly* advise you to avoid giving a namespace and class the same name, and following .NET naming conventions. (PORT and IP should probably be `const` and `PORT` should be named `Port`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have my problem which I solved. So try this:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
await client.Connect​Async(​IP, PORT);
```

I guess you are using `.NET Core`. I hope to be helpful for you :)